# Binding to runtime loaded XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, runtime

I had en idea, which shortly explained was that i would like to load xaml-files runtime, and then bind them to runtime data.
Inside these xaml-files i would use a component called "PropertySetter" like this:

```
public class PropertySetter : UserControl
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    public PropertySetter()
    {
    }
}
```

And the xamlfile, would look like this:

```
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
    xmlns:vf="clr-namespace:VisualFactory.vfGraphics.Graphics;assembly=VisualFactory">
    <vf:PropertySetter Name="Datapoint" Text="propset" Value="false" Adress="10201"  />
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Datapoint, Path=Value}" Content="{Binding ElementName=Datapoint, Path=Text}" />
</Grid>
```

I hope you get the point by now.
The checkbox would bind its values (content, ischecked) to a propertysetter, and when the application runs, it just changes the values of a bunch of "PropertySetter"'s and the graphics update their content and values.
BUT: While the xaml correctly sets the values when it is loaded, it doesnt update them, when i change the values of the propertysetters. I have tried setting Mode=TwoWay, and the propertysetters are in a iNotify collection.
Has anyone tried something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lays in the "DependencyProperty" class. I changed the PropertySetter to this:

```
 public class PropertySetter : UserControl
    {
        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(PropertySetter), new UIPropertyMetadata("0"));




        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(PropertySetter), new UIPropertyMetadata("def"));




        public string Adress
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(AdressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AdressProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AdressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Adress", typeof(string), typeof(PropertySetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));



        public PropertySetter():base()
        {
        }
    }
```

And voilá, it all binds correctly, and i have now made a layer in between runtime loaded XAML and app-logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `PropertySetter` class and fire the `PropertyChanged` event in the setters of each of your properties. This is the mechanism by which the binding knows to update the UI on changes to the source.

```
class PropertySetter :UserControl,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string address;
    private string text;
    private string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (value == value)
                return;
            value = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text == value)
                return;
            text = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            if (address == value)
                return;
            address = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Address"));
        }
    }

    public PropertySetter()
    {

    }
}
```

**PS:** for the `TwoWay` databinding, that is used to tell the databinding that when changes are made in the **target** (in your case, the `CheckBox`'s properties), those are reflected in the **source** (in your case, the `PropertySetter`'s properties).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi AbdouThank for the answer, but i already tried that one to no avail :)

Comment: But i found the answer here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html#creation
I just need to use a DependencyProperty in the propertysetter class.

Comment: Oh! yeah, that was going to be my first response, and it is indeed the problem because you are setting the values in XAML, but then I read the question and just forgot about that and only saw that you're not doing change notification. However, I'm sure why you would need the `PropertySetter` to be created in XAML (I was going to add that remark also)